# Create a subclass whose superclass is known only when it is being created

Tags: python, design-patterns, pyqt, decorator, factory

## Problem

I want a convenient way to create a widget that has a QHBoxLayout or QVBoxLayout as its layout. The type of the widget could be any container widget unknown initially and but specified upon creation.

### Usage

#### As a class decorator

I am repeating a lot of code similar to this. ie. creating the layout and setting it as the layout for the parent widget before adding items.

```
# Insted of this
class JukeBox(QDialog):
    PLAYING, STOPPED, PAUSED = range(3)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JukeBox, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.state = STOPPED
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.playBtn = QPushbutton("Play")
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.playBtn)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

# I want to write this
@BoxWidget(QDialog, Qt.Vertical)
class JukeBox:
    PLAYING, STOPPED, PAUSED = range(3)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.state = JukeBox.STOPPED
        self.playBtn = QButton("Play")
        self.layout().addWidget(self.playBtn)
```

#### As a callable

If I can use it as a callable that returns an instance of a specific widget that will be a plus. Then I will not necessarily need to create a subclass each time I wish to use a convenient container widget.

```
# Conveniently create a button box
# without having to write a subclass
btnBox = BoxedWidget(QFrame, Qt.Horizontal)
btnBox.addtoLayout(QPushbutton("OK"))
btnBox.addtoLayout(QPushbutton("Cancel")
```

### Possible Solutions

From the research that I've done it seems the following solutions may solve the problem.

**Override __new__**: I really do not understand the mechanism and behind the scenes work of the `__new__` method despite all the blog posts I've read. I mean I do not understand enough to even ask the right questions.

**Use a metaclass**: I'm not really sure about if this solution is possible but like the `__new__` I don't really understand the mechanism

**Create a factory function**: Create a `BoxedMainWindow`, `BoxedDialog`, `BoxedFrame` subclasses of BoxedWidget. The factory function then decides from the parameters which type to use in the creation of the instance. I may have to override certain portions in the various subclasses while the need for that can be eliminated by other solutions

**Create a decorator class/function**: I understand decorators a bit. This is what I hacked together and needless to say it is failing.

```
def boxedWidget(Cls, orient=Qt.Horizontal):

    @functools.wraps
    class BoxedWidget:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.widgetInstance = Cls(*args, **kwargs)
            layout = QHBoxLayout()
            if orient == Qt.Vertical:
                layout = QVBoxLayout()
            self.widgetInstance.setLayout(layout)

        def addtoLayout(self, widget, *args, **kwargs):
            layout = self.widgetInstance.layout()
            layout.addWidget(widget, *args, **kwargs)

    return BoxedWidget
```

The error message: `AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'layoutWidget'`

I am open to all solutions though I prefer the fourth one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why can't you just use one of the solutions you already have? It looks like you are asking for opinions on which is the "best" one.

Comment: @ekhumoro I outlined the possible solutions to make it obvious I've done some research. I wanted to implement the fourth one since I understood the process a little better than the others. That is not working and that is what I want help with even though I've obviously stated that any other method will be accepted.

Comment: Not sure because I skimmed, but mixins with a direct call to `type` might be an option here.

Comment: Also, went not extend something simpler, like a panel, and just add your jukebox to a dialog? I'm pretty sure widgets are conceptually meant to be added to stuff, not extend stuff.

Comment: @Charitoo. I cannot see what the problem is. A layout can be added to a widget in literally one line of code: `layout = QVBoxLayout(self)` - you don't even have to call `setLayout`. How is that inconvenient? To me, all that decorator guff looks inconvenient, because it makes it much harder to understand what the code is doing.